# ActiveDirectory: How to find if a domain is available?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there any way of finding out if a domain is available in ActiveDirectory before using GetDomain? I have an app where users should be able to add domains by themselves, and if they enter an invalid domain there should be an error. Right now it is handled by catching the exception below, but a user entering an invalid domain is hardly an exceptional happening, and the exception also can take a really long time to get thrown, especially if an ip adress is entered (it seems like). Is there a better solution to this?

```
public Domain RegisterUserDirectory(string domainId) {
  DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domainId);

  System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain domain;
  try {
    domain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(context);
  }
  catch (ActiveDirectoryNotFoundException adne) {
    // handle
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Log.Warning("Failed to contact domain {0}: {1}", domainId, e.Message);
    throw;
  }

  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think this **is** the best way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately i think there is no real other way. Just think about how you verify that an ip address is reachable. All you can do is try a connection or send an ping request. After this you just have to wait if someone will answer and due to the fact that the connection could be slow the timeouts are high and you have to wait all the time.

All you can do for a better user experience is to put this job into another tread (or background worker) so that your GUI is still responsive and showing some progress or marquee bar to the user. Then you could also add the possibility for the user to cancel the connection tryout by simply aborting this thread.

So this wouldn't make it any faster but give a better responsive to the user and so it feels faster at last.

Answer (score 5):

The only other option I can think of is using the forest to enumerate the domains. i.e.

```
 var myDomain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();  //or .GetComputerDomain();
 var forestDomains = myDomain.Forest.Domains;
```

This assumes all the domains you want are in the same forest.  You'd then need to test your user inputed `domainId` against this collection, probably testing against each domains `.Name` property.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, do I need to do a foreach on the collection to see if it has the domain? or there is any find method?

Comment: @RonenFestinger: I'm not aware of a search/find method, and the [MSDN docs on DomainCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domaincollection(v=vs.110).aspx) don't mention one.  I'm also not sure which properties you'd need to check for each domain (i.e. the domain name you're looking for could be in user@fully.qualified.domain.name format or could be in FQDN\user format - and the NetBIOS and post-2000 names don't always match!)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the way I do it, without using a Forest. Some read-only servers have issues using the Forest class, so if I get an exception with my regular DomainExists method, I try this one instead.

```
public static bool DomainExistsNoForests(string domain, string server)
{
  try {
    DirectoryContext directoryContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, server);
    Domain d = Domain.GetDomain(directoryContext);
    if (d.Name.Trim().Equals(domain.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) return true;
    return false;
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is far, far faster than the way you posted. This code doesn't attempt to resolve the domain, but you do need to know the directory server you're using.

I also have some code in there to check for null arguments, but I trimmed it out for this reply.

Charles.

Answer (score 1):

We need more information to give you a good answer.  Active Directory does store information about all the trusted domains.  So, it's possible to find out all the trusted domain information just by looking at the Global Catalog and without really binding to the domain controller.

However, you need to be aware that even if the domain information exists on the Active Directory, it doesn't mean you can bind to it.  You may not have permissions to bind to it or the firewall settings in your environment may have blocked your access to some domains.

I am assuming the following things here.

1. The computer running your software is joined to a domain already.
2. You are logging in as a domain user when running the software
3. You have only one single forest but the forest includes a lot of domains
4. You have a Global Catalog in your forest (very often, you have)
5. You are entering a DNS domain name but not NETBIOS domain name

You can use the following code to check whether the domain exists in your current forest.  If yes, then continue to call Domain.GetDomain(context) to get your Domain object.  If for some reasons, you cannot bind to it, you still need to wait for the timeout happen.

```
private bool DomainExist(string domain)
{
    HashSet<string> domains = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (Domain d in Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains)
    {
        domains.Add(d.Name.ToLower());
    }

    return domains.Contains(domain.ToLower());
}
```